# How do I get more zebras?

Tags: kittens-game

One of the achievements is:

> Heart Of Darkness -Become a chieftain of a zebra tribe. (How is this
>   even possible?) - Have more then one zebra (sic)

I already have my first Zebra which I got when I built a ship. I only don't know how to get a second Zebra.

So how do I get the 2nd Zebra?

And do they add something more than just the achievement?

Comment: In the wiki it says: "zebras - only available as a resource in Iron Will mode. Acts as hunters.".

Comment: UPDATE! The latest patch fixes zebra loss over resets (from change-log): Karma zebras now save over resets correctly. (http://redd.it/2j0qlo)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> I already have my first Zebra which I got when I built a ship.

This sounds to me very much like you do *not* have a zebra. You have instead discovered the zebra race for trading. In order to get an actual zebra joining your village, you will need to play in Iron Will mode (no huts/log houses/mansions built). You will know you've done it right when a Zebra shows up as an actual resource on the left section.

Zebras in Iron Will are a free way to get some small amount of Catpower, which is otherwise impossible without kittens. To make successive Iron Will runs a little easier, every time you reset, your maximum number of zebras will be set to your current zebra count, plus one.

Comment: When are you awarded a Zebra? I restarted my first game (no IW) and busy figuring things out now, but no zebra.

Comment: Needs archery, same as normal hunters. Most IW stuff doesn't kick in right away, since every game is IW to start.

Answer (score 5):

I've gone through the code and this is the only line that increases the number of zebras you have:

```
reset: function(){
  ...
  this.karmaZebras = this.resPool.get("zebras").value + 1;
  ...
}
```

This would seem to imply you get a single zebra each time you reset.

Comment: Ouch, only 1 way to find out I guess...

Comment: First save, and please post your results :)

Comment: I'm afraid to try...

Comment: I reset with 71 kittens, and no zebra. Damn

Comment: If you believe Billy Mailman's answer, it appears that this.karmaZebras is your maximum zebra count, and this.resPool.get("zebras").value is your current number of zebras (in the current game).

Comment: I think the key code is in calendar.js line 205: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f2dc32ee46e8069a

Comment: Does this mean that resetting without a zebra when your max zebra is say, 5, reset the max back to 1? Correct me if I'm wrong, but that sound like... ouch.

Comment: I'm glad I'm not a completionist, because I've gone right off of iron will mode.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, you get a zebra soon after you get into Iron Will mode, which is achieved by getting the achievement (Iron Will) by building a mine without housing. Then the IW tab appears in Bonfire so you can shut out all the housing options without accidentally hitting one. I entered Iron Will on my 10th run and got 1 zebra... so yes, if there were potential zebras for resets they donèt count until you get your first one. Im almost done IW, curious to see if my zebra will leave when I start making kittens. If not I believe that if I reset and get into IW mode again, I should have more than one zebra and get the achievement.

Answer (score 0):

From experience (i've been trying IW mode for the achievements it provides) You get your first zebra when you learn archery.
Every time i've reseted since trying IW gave me 1 more to the max count of zebras but i waited to have the max count of zebras before reseting.
I did this to ensure having more zebras for next run.

I'm not sure if it is related but : 
the first 4 times i had (in Time tab) : "Zebra hunters: 1"
This time i went on the get the achievements, and i am between steamworks and magneto at this point (which mean achievements Iron will, uberkatzchen, one hundred years of solitude has been fulfilled. i have virgin soiled upturned too), i have 5 zebras with a max of 5 zebras but in the time tab it show "Zebra hunters: 14"
I don't know how this number grows or if it will be add to my next maximum of zebras, though.